# How to measure average cold start time with JMH?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

In JMH(Java Microbenchmark Harness), we can use

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
```

to evaluate the average time of an execution after JVM warms up.

Also we can use

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
@Measurement(iterations = 1)
```

to estimate the cold start time of an execution. But this only executes the benchmark once, which may introduce bias. So is there any method to evaluate the average time of the cold start in JMH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Alexey himself](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2014-May/000807.html) (though from 2014):

> Single-shot benchmarks were originally destined to run a single
> measurement iteration over multiple forks -- the scenarios to estimate
> "cold" performance. But for many cases, you might want more measurement
> iterations there especially if you are running only a single fork,
> because more samples would be generated.

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class AverageSingleShot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(AverageSingleShot.class.getSimpleName())
            .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Fork(100)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
    public int test() {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt() + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt();
    }

}
```

Besides the fact that this will tell you the *average* (see that `100`):

```
 Benchmark               Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
 AverageSingleShot.test    ss  100  41173.540 ± 2871.546  ns/op
```

you will also get `Percentiles` and a `Histogram`.

Comment: Why Measurement and Warmup with iterations of 100? Isn't that counterproductive?

Comment: @knittl edited. `Warmup` is indeed wrong, but `Measurement` might depend on what your test does. If you want to measure `invokedynamic` times (that are expensive in the first invocation) - you might be right, but in the test above `C1` compiler will not come to life for 100 invocations so this is treated at "cold" too, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, it works! Also I'm wondering how to make the methods in one benchmark run sequentially in the main thread?

Comment: @Thesharing can you ask a separate question may be?

Comment: Here's the separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177915/how-to-run-methods-in-benchmarks-sequentially-with-jmh And thank you so much for your generous help.